# DAX Power BI - how to count how many ID's appear in table more then 5 times

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

What I try to achieve is to count how many ID's from one table appear in second table more then 5 times + it meets 2 other parameters.
I have currently code like that:

```
Measure =
CALCULATE (
    COUNTROWS (
        FILTER ( 'Activity', CONTAINS ( 'Incident', [id], 'Activity'[key_value] ) )
    ) > 5,
    'Activity'[action] = 160,
    Activity[object_class] = 1
)
```

Column ID from Incident is relation to Activity key_value

Comment: is there an active relationship between the tables?

Comment: @Stachu yes ofcourse.

Answer (score 1):

try this measure

```
Measure = 
VAR __activity = FILTER(
    ALL('Activity'),
    'Activity'[action] = 160 
    && 'Activity'[object_class] = 1  
    && COUNTROWS(RELATEDTABLE(Incident)) > 5)
RETURN
COUNTROWS(__activity)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer however this returns empty/null. When i delete "> 5" it counts all rows correctly. In database there is more then 5 rows with one ID so it should work correctly

Comment: what's the relationship between `Activity` and `Incident`? I assume it's not single direction 1:many, on `Activity[key_value]=Incident[id]` with Incident being on the many side?

Comment: Many to single
Activity being on the many side Incident on the single side. It's both direction

Comment: I added ALL around Activity, so it would not be dependant on the filter context, it should return normally now

Comment: Still same result with >5 returns empty.

Comment: I would need more information about your model, it works with my recreated sample, but that's most likely because my case is more simplified

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227234/discussion-between-uberxeq-and-stachu).

Comment: Or let me know what information do you need about model. I disabled all other relations in database for test purposes but it still returns empty